# fecha en netbens con java

Tags: java, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola necesito ayuda en un codigo, que me logre mostrar la fecha del dia en una caja de texto en netbens , tengo ya hecho el codigo pero me muestra un mes de atrasado , me pudieran ayudar por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hay varias opciones para hacerlo, en tu caso con lo siguiente ya estaría,añadelo justo despues de Calendar.getInstance:

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

pero hay más opciones espero que te sirvan:

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String mesActual = mCalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

Te recomiendo configurar un LOCALE adecuado para que se muestre en tu idioma por ejemplo:

```
Locale localeSpanish = new Locale("es", "ES");
String mesActual = mCalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, localeSpanish);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, lo logre solucionar uwu <3